# Test Observable.FlatMap Mockito

Tags: java-8, mockito, rx-java

I've been looking on internet but haven't found the solution if any (new on UnitTest and Mockito)

It's possible to test a method that return a call of a service and manipulate it's result before to return it? Example;

```
public Observable<Reports> getUserReports(Integer userId) {
    return serviceClient
        .getReports(userId)
        .flatMap(serviceReports -> {
            System.out.println("Testing inside flatMap"); <- never reach this line therefore duno if methods down here are invoked and work perfectly
            final Observable<List<Report>> reports = getPendingReports(userId, serviceReports);

            //More methods that modify/update information

            return zip(observable1, observable2, observable3
                (report1, report2, report3) -> {
                    updateReports(otherArguments, report1, report2, report3);
                    return serviceReports;
                });

        });
}
```

So far I've tried;

```
@Test
public void myTest(){
        when(serviceClient
            .getReports(anyInt()))
            .thenReturn(Observable.just(reports));

        Observable<Reports> result = mocketClass.getUserReports(userId)
}
```

Tryed with Spy and Mock but no luck so far. Any hint or help would be great.

Comment: how can we mock getPendingReports here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mock `getReports()` behavior you need to mock the `serviceClient` firstly and pass it into your service class.

Just as example:

```
@Test
public void myTest(){
    // Given
    final ServiceClient mockedServiceClient = Mockito.mock(ServiceClient.class);
    when(mockedServiceClient
        .getReports(anyInt()))
        .thenReturn(Observable.just(reports));

    // and create an instance of your class under testing with injected mocked service client.
    final MyUserService userService = new MyUserService();
    userService.setServiceClient(mockedServiceClient);

    // When run a method under test
    Observable<Reports> actualResult = userService.getUserReports(userId)

    // Then
    // actualResult to be verified.
}
```